# Can Vite continue to watch through syntax errors?

Tags: vite, rollupjs

I am running `vite build --watch --mode=development`. Anytime I save a file with a syntax error, the watcher bails with `Command failed with exit code 1`. When I had used Webpack previously, the watcher would keep watching and await the syntax fix. This is causing a number of issues. I found a similar issue for [vitest](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1715) that had been resolved, so I am thinking I must be missing some obvious way around this.

I realized this is due to `@rollup/plugin-typescript`. So my question is related to Vite since Vite relies upon rollup to watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies within https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/258:

`typescript({ noEmitOnError: false })`